# How to link Realm to react native project on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, react-native, realm

My team is trying to add [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) to our react native app.

We did `react-native link realm` on Mac and the app worked fine with Realm on iOS tablets.
But we don't know how to do it for Windows tablets.
We tried `react-native link realm` on Windows, but it didn't make any changes to Windows project files.

Does anyone know how to run and build React Native apps with Realm for Windows tablets?

Thanks!

Comment: no realm support for windows yet

Comment: Technically the Node.js half of Realm's javascript support **does** support UWP, but I don't think it supports Windows via React-Native yet. I'm actually not sure about this. hmm.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like we need to give up now. I hope it'll be supported soon!

Comment: @okyk Please take a look at version 2.0.0-rc21 or 2.0.0-rc22 :-)

Comment: @geisshirt I read the README in those versions, but I couldn't find anything related to Windows tablets. Can you tell me where to read?